# VBA countif and update adjacent cell

Tags: excel, vba

I've tried to write the below snippet of code to perform a "countif" and if the value if greater than zero, update the adjacent cell. Unfortunately, I've not had much luck.

**Sheet5** has the lookup range, **Sheet2** has the lookup value

```
Dim Cell As Variant
Dim lr As Long
Dim lookupvalue As Range
lr = Sheet5.Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set lookupvalue = Sheet2.Range("S3:S20000")
For Each Cell In lookupvalue
If CountIf(lr, (Cell.Value)) > 0 Then
Cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = "message goes here"
End If
Next
```

Comment: VBA doesn't have a countif - you need Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You hadn't defined the lookup range on sheet5.

Given you have quite a lot of data you might want to consider speedier alternatives (why not just a worksheet function?).

```
Sub x()

Dim Cell As Range
Dim lr As Long
Dim lookupvalue As Range

lr = sheet5.Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set lookupvalue = Sheet2.Range("S3:S20000")

For Each Cell In lookupvalue
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sheet5.Range("J1:J" & lr), Cell.Value) > 0 Then
        Cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = "message goes here"
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks a ton! that worked. I didn't want to use a function because I have a ton of other validation code which checks for conditions and updates this one "validation" column.